# How to animate the custom tab indicator in custom tab in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to make a custom tab and animate while changing the tab. The real design for that is

[image]

How can i achieve that?

My code what i have done till now is

```
const UNDERLINE_WIDTH = 60;

const getWidth = (e) => e.nativeEvent.layout.width;

const getInputRange = (routes) => routes.map((_, idx) => idx);

const getOutputRange = ({ inputRange, layout }) => {
  const outputRange = inputRange.map((value, idx) => {
    const itemWidth = parseNumber(layout[idx], 0);
    const sumLeft = sum(layout.slice(0, value));

    const diff = itemWidth - UNDERLINE_WIDTH;
    const offset = Math.abs(Math.floor(diff / 2 + sumLeft));

    return parseNumber(offset, 0);
  });

  if (I18nManager.isRTL) {
    return getArrComplement(outputRange);
  }

  return outputRange;
};

const CustomTab = ({
  index,
  routesOrder,
  onChange,
  ignoreSafeArea = false
}) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const [layout, setLayout] = useState(new Array(routesOrder.length).fill(0));
  const [leftValue] = useState(new Animated.Value(index));

  const inputRange = useMemo(() => getInputRange(routesOrder), [routesOrder]);
  const outputRange = useMemo(
    () => getOutputRange({ inputRange, layout }),
    [inputRange, layout]
  );

  const setRowLayout = (e) => setWidth(getWidth(e));
  const setItemLayout = ({ idx, e }) => {
    if (layout[idx]) {
      return;
    }
    const newLayout = [...layout];
    newLayout[idx] = getWidth(e);
    setLayout(newLayout);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.spring(leftValue, {
      toValue: index,
      bounciness: 5,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();
  }, [index, leftValue]);

  const underlineStyle = [
    {
      height: 6,
      backgroundColor: '#000',
      width: UNDERLINE_WIDTH,
      transform: [
        {
          translateX: leftValue.interpolate({
            inputRange,
            outputRange
          })
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  const Wrapper = ignoreSafeArea ? Column : SafeAreaView;

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Column
        height={HEIGHT}
        borderBottomColor={Colors.gray2}
        borderBottomWidth={0.5}
      >
        <Row justifyContent='center' onLayout={setRowLayout}>
          {routesOrder.map((route, idx) => {
            const { routeKey, label, subroutes } = route;
            const isSelected = idx === index;
            return (
              <Touchable
               
                testID='header-tab-button'
                isSelected={isSelected}
                //  flex={1}
                marginHorizontal={10}
                key={`${routeKey}_${idx}`}
                paddingHorizontal={HORIZONTAL_PADDING}
                onLayout={(e) => setItemLayout({ idx, e })}
                onPress={() =>
                  onChange({
                    index: idx,
                    key: subroutes.length ? subroutes[0].routeKey : routeKey
                  })
                }
              >
                <Column paddingVertical={18} center>
                  <H6
                    testID='header-tab-button-text'
                    isSelected={isSelected}
                    uppercase
                    bold={isSelected}
                  >
                    {label}
                  </H6>
                </Column>
              </Touchable>
            );
          })}
          {!!width && (
            <Float bottom={0}>
              <Animated.View style={underlineStyle} />
            </Float>
          )}
        </Row>
      </Column>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

The problem with this code is that i am not getting correct output value i.e. `getOutputRange` function and due to that the bottom indicator is not properly aligned with the label.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Kindly correct the above code or help me with new code please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: By the way i am not getting correct output value and the bottom indicator is not correctly  aligned with the label

Answer (score 0):

I use the following approach when building an animated tab indicator in RN:

For your interpolation input range, you can simply use the window dimensions, assuming you are also allowing users to pan left-right on the screen to switch which tab they are on:

```
const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();
```

```
const inputRange = data.map((_, index) => {
  return index * width; // [0, width, 2*width, 3*width, ...]
});
```

In the above example `data` is just a simple array of objects containing info about my tabs, such as the title of the tab.

On a screen with 5 tabs this gives you an `inputRange` such as:

```
[0, 390, 780, 1170, 1560]
```

For the output range, with these types of tab components there are usually two things to consider:

1. The x position output range. (WHERE is the underline)
2. The width output range. (HOW WIDE is the underline)

I typically do something like this:

```
// The outputRange will be the x position + the starting x of each section.
const xOutputRange = data.map((_, index) => {
  return (layouts.value[index]?.x ?? 0) + (index * width) / data.length;
});

// The outputRange will be the width of each section title.
const widthOutputRange = data.map((_, index) => {
  return layouts.value[index]?.width ?? 0;
});
```

You can then interpolate on both `x` and `width` as follows:

```
indicatorLayout.value = {
  ...indicatorLayout.value,
  x: interpolate(
    event.contentOffset.x,
    inputRange,
    xOutputRange,
    Extrapolate.CLAMP,
  ),
  width: interpolate(
    event.contentOffset.x,
    inputRange,
    widthOutputRange,
    Extrapolate.CLAMP,
  ),
};
```

In the above code you will notice an `event` value, that is because I have it wrapped inside a scrollHandler, to allow the user to pan left-right to change the tab:

```
const scrollHandler = useAnimatedScrollHandler({
  onScroll: event => {
```

In the above code you will also notice a `layouts` value that I use, this is the key part to making it work:

```
const layouts = useSharedValue<LayoutRectangle[]>([]);
```

This variable is an array of `LayoutRectangle` (import from `react-native`). Each one of these items in the array represents one of the tab titles. At the beginning, the array is empty, but we leverage the `onLayout` event to populate the array. Leveraging the `onLayout` event when we render our titles is the key to making this approach work.

When I am rendering my tab component, when I am rendering the `<Text>` title itself, I use the following:

```
<Text
  onLayout={({ nativeEvent: { layout } }) => {
    layouts.value[index] = { ...layout };
    layouts.value = [...layouts.value];

    // If the index is 0, we update the indicatorLayout value.
    // This is because we want the indicatorLayout value to be
    // the layout of the first section title (at the first render).
    if (index === 0) {
      indicatorLayout.value = { ...layout };
    }
  }}
  style={styles.title}>
  {title}
</Text>
```

Comment: The tabs are in the center of the screen horizontally and the max tabs can be 3